# Converting a table into a data frame - R Studio

Tags: sql, r, datatable, runtime-error

I have the following table which i need to convert to a table and i have the below error which i can't figure out the problem. My main idea is to get a value from a particular column in the table. The view of the table is working fine. Thanks

```
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
     Driver = "SQL Server",
     Server = "MSIGS75\\SQLEXPRESS",
     Database = "Players")

dbListTables(con)
table <- tbl(con, "playersData")
View(tbl(con, "playersData"))

tableDF <- as.data.frame(table)
```

**Error**

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(table) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: You can us `table %>% collect() %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: Please show output of `dbListTables`. Also, `RODBC` and `odbc` are two different, incompatible DB-APIs (but do use same underlying ODBC technology). You are not using the `RODBC` package here.

Comment: Error in UseMethod("collect") : 
  no applicable method for 'collect' applied to an object of class "function" --- I have this error now @akrun

Comment: can you also load `dbplyr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `collect`

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
yourcolumn <- "some column name"
yourindex <- 5# row 5
table %>%
   collect() %>% 
   as.data.frame %>%
   select(yourcolumn) %>%
   slice(yourindex)
```